# On Inno Setup License page, replace checkboxes by "I agree" button

Tags: inno-setup

I'd like to remove the checkboxes *"I accept the agreement"* / *"Don't accept"* and replace the text of the *"Next"* button by a simple *"I agree"*, after all, it looks more clear and straight.

Can you point me to some sample or where to look in the documentation?

Comment: There's a reason that it's done with the radio buttons (as Inno does) almost universally by all companies that do Windows software. It forces the user to stop on the page and figure out what it's asking, and deliberately take an action (changing the radio button from *I do not* to *I accept*) before proceeding. You might want to reconsider things before doing this, IMO. Changing means the user may actually not agree, thinking that they've been clicking *Next*, *Next*, *Next*, *I agree*...Wait, what did I just click? It looked different...  And in court? *All the buttons said "Next".*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Ken pointed out, do not do this, if you need user to really accept the license. As clicking, what seems to be a mere *"Next"* button, hardly constitutes a conscious agreement.

A different thing is, when the user is actually not required to accept the license, like is the case of GPL (which actually [explicitly forbids being required to be accepted](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html#section9)). Then your approach might be ok. Except maybe that you should not change the button to *"I agree"* then.

```pascal
[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  // Hide radio buttons and pre-select "accept", to enable "next" button
  WizardForm.LicenseAcceptedRadio.Checked := True;
  WizardForm.LicenseAcceptedRadio.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.LicenseNotAcceptedRadio.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Height :=
    WizardForm.LicenseNotAcceptedRadio.Top +
    WizardForm.LicenseNotAcceptedRadio.Height -
    WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Top - ScaleY(5);
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  // Dubious, but you have asked for it
  if CurPageID = wpLicense then
  begin
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := '&I agree';
  end;
end;
```

[image]