# How to change default choice in License agreement in INNO Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I use

```
LicenseFile="....txt"
```

in Inno Setup.
Radio button *"I do not accept the agreement"* is the default choice in in license page. How do I change the default to *"I accept the agreement"*?

Thanks.

Comment: Add the following line to your code within the InitializeWizard procedure:
`WizardForm.LicenseAcceptedRadio.Checked := True;`
See the inno setup documentation for more information.

Comment: But isn’t that the point? They need to consciously accept the terms. You should not assume IMHO. I know of none that default to “yes”.

Comment: Related question: [On Inno Setup License page, replace checkboxes by "I agree" button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51290580/850848).